# My HP Pavilion will only start after 2-3 reboots. Every time

Tags: boot, reboot, hp-pavilion

I have a **HP ENVY h8-1514eo** stationary PC, model **D7A59EA**, and it has the weirdest problem. When I boot it, it always fails the first 1-3 times. This makes it impossible to run Windows updates since that requires a reboot and it always fails on that reboot. I have to manually turn it off and on a couple of times in order to get it up and running again. [I have asked this question on HP's support forum](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Boot-and-Lockup/HP-Pavilion-stuck-on-boot-black-screen-when-monitor-is/m-p/5657902) but I haven't had a single answer in 3 months and generally SuperUser is a lot faster than that :)

Now, what I have noticed is that every time it fails I get the same loop in the disc-icon led. It blinks very fast about 8-10 times, goes dark for half a second, and then blink once more. Then does it over and over and over again until I forcefully reboot. Here is a video showing it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1V1jZWKpUQ

This was a problem that started to occur after I purchased a new monitor (**Acer 27" Predator XB270HU G-Sync**), but I can't see how the monitor would ruin the computer. I did notice that the computer tends to start when I unhook the monitor prior to start, but that also feels a bit superstitious.

Comment: Try disconnecting all unneeded USB devices and reboot.

Comment: @DavidPostill: just tried it and that didn't help :(